# Reading 3 bytes as an integer

Tags: python

How can I read 3 bytes as an integer?

Does struct module provide something like that?

I can read in 3 bytes and add an extra \x00 and then interpret it as a 4-byte integer, but that seems unnecessary.

Comment: Make sure you add the NUL to the right end...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The struct module has no option for 3-byte integers, so I think your idea of appending '\x00' is the easiest way.

```
In [30]: import struct
In [38]: struct.pack('>3b',0,0,1)
Out[38]: '\x00\x00\x01'

In [39]: struct.unpack('>i','\x00'+'\x00\x00\x01')
Out[39]: (1,)
```

Answer (score 13):

I think from 3.2, `int` developed a new method `.from_bytes`, so you're able to use the following instead of `struct.unpack`:

```
int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x00\x01', 'big')  
# 1
```

For reference, see: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes

Answer (score 3):

An alternative for python 2 and without the `struct` module would be:

```
>>> s = '\x61\x62\xff'
>>> a = sum([ord(b) * 2**(8*n) for (b, n) in zip(s, range(len(s))[::-1])])
>>> print a
6382335
```

where the byte ordering is big-endian. This gives the same result as with
[unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu) answer:

```
>>> print struct.unpack('>I', '\x00' + s)[0]
6382335
```

For little-endian byte ordering the conversion would be:

```
>>> a = sum([ord(b) * 2**(8*n) for (b, n) in zip(s, range(len(s)))])
>>> print a
16736865
>>> print struct.unpack('<I', s + '\x00')[0]
16736865
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just do the bit shifting yourself.

Big Endian:

```
ba = # 3 byte bytearray
v = ba[0] << 16 | ba[1] << 8 | ba[2]
```

Little Endian

```
ba = # 3 byte bytearray
v = ba[2] << 16 | ba[1] << 8 | ba[0]
```