# python; struct; repeat count for 24-bit integers

Tags: python, struct

I want to unpack array of 2760 bytes, to new array of 920 24-bit integers. Unlike e.g. 16 bit integers, where would `struct.unpack_from('920h',array,0)` do the thing, you can't use 'repeat count' syntax with 24 bit integers:

```
struct.unpack_from('920<i', array,0 )
```

This gives the following error: 'bad count in struct format'.

So what's the syntax for 24 bit integers? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: There is no explicit support for 24-bit integers, no. I'd pad them out to 32 bits, then unpack those using `I`.

Comment: See [Reading 3 bytes as an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10216650) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct` does not natively support 24-bit integers.

If these are *unsigned* integers, on trick you could use is to use the [`array.array()` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) to read the data as bytes, then process these per 3:

```
import array

b = array.array('B', yourdata)
result = [b[i] << 16 | b[i + 1] << 8 | b[i + 2] for i in xrange(0, len(b), 3)]
```

or you could use [`array.fromfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#array.array.fromfile) to read the data from a file input as needed:

```
with open('somefilename', 'rb') as infh:
    b = array.array('B')
    b.fromfile(infh, 920)
    result = [b[i] << 16 | b[i + 1] << 8 | b[i + 2] for i in xrange(0, len(b), 3)]
```

Adjust as needed for byte order (swap the `b[i]` and `b[i + 2]` references).

If these are *signed* 24-bit integers, you may have to stick to `struct`, and pad the *least significant side* with a null-byte, then right-shift the result by 8. That way you don't have to worry about negative vs. positive numbers and how to pad either type on the most-significant side:

```
[struct.unpack('>i', yourdata[i:i+3] + '\x00')[0] >> 8
 for i in range(0, len(yourdata), 3)]
```

for big-endian, and

```
[struct.unpack('<i', '\x00' + yourdata[i:i+3])[0] >> 8
 for i in range(0, len(yourdata), 3)]
```

for little-endian signed 24-bit integers.

If you are using Python 3.2 or newer, you can read the data 3 bytes at a time and convert to integers with [`int.from_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes), which gives you more flexibility over endianess and if you are parsing signed or unsigned integers.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same, but then I have to pass counter-variable as argument to `unpack` function. I didn't read about that. Offset would be `i`, in that case

Comment: @roberto: are these integers signed or unsigned?

Comment: I didn't check; but I suppose they are signed. But tell me is it possible to specify `i` variable (loop counter) as offset in struct?

Comment: You must specify an offset, but in all examples it is explicit numerical value. I didn't see any example with variable offset. Without that ability, there's no looping.

Comment: The offset is optional, and only when using `.unpack_from()`.

Comment: Ok, I will use one of these solutions; the main thing is that `struct` has no simple syntax for this task, as I thought it should. Thanks for help.